# PHP Rebuild Multi-Dimensional Array if array elements are missing

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a `Multi-Dimesional` I would like to rebuild this array so that all first level array's (`array[]`) that have the missing data that another array has (basically replacing missing data). I am building a graph with this array, so I need to fill the missing areas with `0` otherwise there are huge holes in my Graph.

`[numberof]` is the amount for this given plot.
`[date]` is the month that it occurred. As you can see I am order from today's month (3) `ASC`:

**Current Output**

```
Array
 (
[First] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [numberof] => 1
                [date] => 12
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [numberof] => 2
                [date] => 1
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [numberof] => 2
                [date] => 2
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [numberof] => 25
                [date] => 3
            )

    )

[Second] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [numberof] => 1
                [date] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [numberof] => 2
                [date] => 2
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [numberof] => 1
                [date] => 3
            )

    )

[Third] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [numberof] => 1
                [date] => 2
            )

    )
)
```

**Desired Outcome**

```
Array
 (
[First] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [numberof] => 1
                [date] => 12
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [numberof] => 2
                [date] => 1
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [numberof] => 2
                [date] => 2
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [numberof] => 25
                [date] => 3
            )

    )

[Second] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array //ADDED and given a value of 0
            (
                [numberof] => 0
                [date] => 12
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [numberof] => 1
                [date] => 1
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [numberof] => 2
                [date] => 2
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [numberof] => 1
                [date] => 3
            )

    )

[Third] => Array
    (

        [0] => Array //ADDED and given a value of 0
            (
                [numberof] => 0
                [date] => 12
            )

        [1] => Array  //ADDED and given a value of 0
            (
                [numberof] => 0
                [date] => 1
            )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [numberof] => 1
                [date] => 2
            )

        [3] => Array //ADDED and given a value of 0
            (
                [numberof] => 0
                [date] => 3
            )
    )
)
```

To my mind this is just impossible. But maybe I've not got the skills, what I've tried so far:

**n.b this is me talking out loud**
.... I just can't get my head around how to do it, loop through arrays, check if it has a value numbr, if it doesn't add it. But what if the last row is the one with the most months and the first month only has 1 month?

**EDIT**

`MySQL`:

```
$sql = sprintf("SELECT count(*) as numberOf, MONTH(s.sextime) as date FROM sex s, users u WHERE %s AND s.uid = u.uid AND s.sextime >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL %d MONTH) GROUP BY MONTH(s.sextime) ORDER BY s.sextime ASC;", $type, $months);
```

This is the PHP generating the above arrays and calling the sql:

```
    $info['info']['First'] = $this->dataStore->grabSexesByMonth('AND s.sexnumber=1');
    $info['info']['Second'] = $this->dataStore->grabSexesByMonth('AND s.sexnumber=2');
    $info['info']['Third'] = $this->dataStore->grabSexesByMonth('AND s.sexnumber=3');
```

Comment: Could you paste the code that's generating the current output?

Comment: does every added element have to have a date value that the [First] array has?

Comment: I would modify the SQL query that is producing that array instead. Can you post the query itself?

Comment: @zogby In this example the [first] has the highest values, but this could change at any point to be [Second] having the highest number, or [Third]. As people will have different stats from user to user I can never say which month will be the most active, but I need to copy from the month that this the **MOST** active.

Comment: @KouberSaparev I certainly can edit the SQL. One sec i'll update with the query. Sadly I'd need to include the query then?

Comment: Well, that seems to be the proper way to solve the issue, because it might happen that you do not have the complete values neither in the `First`, nor in the `Second`, etc. elements, hence no way to know in advance what and where to fill with zeros. Put also the RDBMS you are using along with the query itself, if you can.

Comment: @KouberSaparev my big problem is how I am storing the data, I don't believe I can grab it out in any other way... Thanks for the help all the same, I've gone insane this morning.

Comment: @KouberSaparev RDBMS? I am can't really see how I can change the query.

Answer (score 0):

A 3-step process may work:

```
$fillTo = array('key'=>'','count'=>0);
foreach($array as $k => $data) {
    if (count($data) > $fillTo['count']) {
        $fillTo['key'] = $k;
        $fillTo['count'] = count($data);
    }
}

$fillData = $array[$fillTo['key']];
foreach($fillData as $k => &$data) {
    $data['numberof'] => 0;
}

foreach($array as $k => &$data) {
    if ($k === $fillTo['key'])
        continue;

    $data = $data + $fillData;
}

var_dump($array);
```

Comment: A few steps was where my brain was heading. I'll try and wrap my head round this :) Give me a few... See if I can get anywhere with it

Comment: Basically it just checks which key has the most values, sets some buffer fill data using this array set (replacing the numberof with 0) then fills the other arrays with that data.

Comment: Ye ok, nice one. and `$array` is basically the array that has the data. Wish me luck

Comment: O I will, if you can fix this problem I'll also hug you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `MySQL` does not have a set returning function, such as the `PostgreSQL` [generate_series](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html#FUNCTIONS-SRF-SERIES) for example. That complicates the things a bit, as you need to generate the set of all the dates programatically. Also, instead of `MONTH(sextime)` you should use `EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM sextime)`, as otherwise you will have mixed sums for months from different years.

```
$months = 4;

# emulate GENERATE_SERIES
for ($i = $months-1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
  $gen_series[] = "SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL $i MONTH) extr";
}
$gen_series = join(' UNION ', $gen_series);


$sql = sprintf("SELECT
                  fll.sexnumber,
                  fll.extr as date,
                  COUNT(u.uid) as numberOf
                FROM
                  (SELECT
                    dts.extr,
                    sxn.sexnumber
                  FROM
                    (%s) dts,
                    (SELECT DISTINCT sexnumber FROM sex) sxn) fll LEFT JOIN sex s
                ON
                  fll.extr = EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM s.sextime) AND fll.sexnumber=s.sexnumber LEFT JOIN users u
                ON
                  s.uid = u.uid
                GROUP BY
                  fll.sexnumber,
                  fll.extr
                ORDER BY
                  fll.sexnumber,
                  fll.extr", $gen_series);

echo $sql;
```

The above PHP code will output the following SQL query.

```
SELECT
  fll.sexnumber,
  fll.extr as date,
  COUNT(u.uid) as numberOf
FROM
  (SELECT
    dts.extr,
    sxn.sexnumber
  FROM
    (SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 3 MONTH) extr UNION SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 2 MONTH) extr UNION SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) extr UNION SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 0 MONTH) extr) dts,
    (SELECT DISTINCT sexnumber FROM sex) sxn) fll LEFT JOIN sex s
ON
  fll.extr = EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM s.sextime) AND fll.sexnumber=s.sexnumber LEFT JOIN users u
ON
  s.uid = u.uid
GROUP BY
  fll.sexnumber,
  fll.extr
ORDER BY
  fll.sexnumber,
  fll.extr;
```

Running it over the same dataset, you will get the following output from MySQL.

```
+-----------+--------+----------+
| sexnumber | date   | numberOf |
+-----------+--------+----------+
|         1 | 201312 |        1 |
|         1 | 201401 |        2 |
|         1 | 201402 |        2 |
|         1 | 201403 |       25 |
|         2 | 201312 |        0 |
|         2 | 201401 |        1 |
|         2 | 201402 |        2 |
|         2 | 201403 |        1 |
|         3 | 201312 |        0 |
|         3 | 201401 |        0 |
|         3 | 201402 |        1 |
|         3 | 201403 |        0 |
+-----------+--------+----------+
12 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

So you get what you need with just 1 query (instead of 3) and no redundant arrays juggling.